# TypeScript declare method return type is instance type of class or subclass

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

Is there a way in typescript to declare a method that returns the type of the current instance?

For example:

```
class AnimalBuilder {

    withColor:(color: Color): AnimalBuilder    { 
       this.color = color; 
       return this; 
    } 

}

class DogBuilder extends AnimalBuilder { 
    //builder methods specific to a dog. 
}
```

. . such that calling

```
new DogBuilder().withColor()
```

will have a return type of `DogBuilder` not `AnimalBuilder`. In objective-c such a thing is called `instancetype`. I checked out `InstanceType<T>` in TypeScript but couldn't figure out whether it was talking about the same thing or not.

This would allow chaining builder methods on the super class and the subclass in any order, eg:

```
new DogBuilder().withColor(Color.BLUE).withBreed(breed).withEtc()
```

. . without having to add any extra cruft on subclasses to support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just omit return parameter in you base classes or you can return `this` if you want to show return type on method (maybe a bit cleaner).

```
class AnimalBuilder {
    color?: Color;
    withColor(color: Color): this { 
       this.color = color; 
       return this; 
    } 
}
```

Please see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=60#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJygXigbwL4G4BQ+AxggIYDO5UAggHYCWAtqQgEICu9CAJhKpvihCoRRCgD8ALlhjkBYVADu9YAAt4SZAApRm6RpQBKaWvpVMUQQqGnyAOl0p0I2bkvWhyCMHbJaUWzcrIWxLbEJQSChWLwhuZxwCYjJKKAAROABzDi5eVAgAD2AIWm4qOiYWHJ4+LHdhAHoGgCNOGtRGb1U4MqhySCJ6ADN6IgC4KFIobiy7eqFlNRiIOK1m2O5pZbjjdKzqvKxg6y8fPwDVM3lhcPD8BG8oVtzajFoIRT3strytQztFupZFocP9AdtuCDsIZcEA).